# What will too much Caramunich do to my beer

Tags: specialty-grains, saison

Making Jamil's saison today:

10.5# pilsner
.75# wheat malt
.75# munich

it is supposed to have 2oz of caramunich, but instead I measured, milled, and then MIXED with the rest of the grain .75 LBS (12oz) of caramunich.  Yes, six times the recipe.

I know caramunich will add body, caramel, and sweetness (the latter very NOT appropriate for the style), HOWEVER, here is the catch:

I am planning on doing a secondary fermentation with this beer with 3-4lbs of fresh cranberries for our brewing guild Christmas party.  Would this sweetness help to balance out the tartness/sourness of the cranberries, or will it simply just be too much?  The good thing is, I have kind of written off hitting my color completely, as I've read around the interwebs that cranberries will add a brownish color to the beer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you will have a problem at all - even though it is technically 6x the recipe, it is still a relatively small proportion of your whole batch, which is mostly pils.  Sure, the color won't be as light, but I think the sweetness won't be crazy overwhelming with under 1lb and will probably be nice to have another flavor in the beer aside from straight up cranberry.  What you can do to be safe is to draw off a sample before secondary fermentation, put it in the fridge (to at least normalize for the temp factor of drinking finished beer), and then throw a cranberry or two in there and taste it.  Sure, it's a rough estimate, but you might have some clues about how much/if to add the cranberries.  I certainly don't think your beer concept is ruined, it'll probably be great!  :-)

Sheri

Comment: Agreed; fruit will ferment out pretty well, and considering it's cranberries, the additional sweetness will probably help balance it out.